# How to rotate client secrets on Azure Dev Ops OAuth client application

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

About a year ago we created an OAuth client application in Azure Dev Ops to allow our SaaS product to integrate with Azure Dev Ops.  We are now interested in rotating the client secret but I find no facility for this in the Azure Dev Ops portal (https://aex.dev.azure.com/).

Does Azure Dev Ops provide a mechanism for client secret rotation?